# Check failed: Loss::CheckLabel(y) label must be in [0,1] for logistic regression

Tags: r, xgboost

Is this a bug with train function `xgboost()` ? The train labels are updated as `numeric` but still i see the same error that the labels must be [0,1] for log reg.

#### What i have tried.

First method.

```
train.y <- as.factor(train.y)

levels(train.y)[levels(train.y) =='klar'] <- 0
levels(train.y)[levels(train.y) =='trüb'] <- 1
train.y <- as.numeric(train.y)
```

#### alternative

Second method.

```
train.y <- as.numeric(as.factor(train.y))

> class(train.y)
[1] "numeric"


# convert dataset into Dmatrix
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data =as.matrix(train.x), label= train.y)

# train model 
model.xgb <- xgboost(data = dtrain, # the data   
                     max.depth = 3,
                     nround = 50, # boosting iterations
                     objective = "binary:logistic")  # the objective function
```

#### Error

```
Error in xgb.iter.update(bst$handle, dtrain, iteration - 1, obj) : 
  [12:55:32] amalgamation/../src/objective/regression_obj.cc:98: Check failed: Loss::CheckLabel(y) label must be in [0,1] for logistic regression
```

How can i get around this ?

Similar issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48999589/r-xgboost-label-must-be-in-0-1-for-logistic-regression). I have reported this [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/3662) but just in case if someone has already solve this.

Here is a reproducible example.

#### Reproducible example

```
train.x <- matrix(rexp(5000), ncol = 10)

train.y <- rep(c('klar', 'trüb'), times=250)
train.y <- as.numeric(as.factor(train.y))

dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(train.x), label=train.y)
```

Comment: `train.y <- as.numeric(as.factor(train.y)) - 1` is worth a shot since `as.numeric(as.factor(train.y))` produces a vector of `1` and `2` and not of `0` and `1`.

Comment: @missuse Ah. Ok i get it. Works now. Thank you.